# Using numberOfTouchesRequired to implement secondary click with TrackPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipados

I want to implement the secondary click on iPad to show options.

```
let tapTwoRecog = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapTwoAsLongPress(gesture:)))
        tapTwoRecog.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
        tapTwoRecog.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapTwoRecog.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouch.TouchType.direct.rawValue), NSNumber(value: UITouch.TouchType.indirect.rawValue)]
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapTwoRecog)
        tableView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
```

But it only be triggered by the touches on the screen.
Using trackpad doesn't trigger anything.
I've already set the `UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents` to `YES/NO`.

Comment: The meaning of a two finger touch is negotiated between the trackpad and the device. Your app has no say in the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an answer from this site:
https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2020/level-up-your-trackpad-support-using-uiinteraction/

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
    let tapTwoRecog = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapTwoAsLongPress(gesture:)))
    tapTwoRecog.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouch.TouchType.indirectPointer.rawValue)]
    tapTwoRecog.buttonMaskRequired = .secondary
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapTwoRecog)
}
```

The `UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents` must be `YES`.