# Clicking the right mouse button. Mac M1 (Designed for iPad)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, apple-m1

We have an iOS application. It has support for Mac M1 (Designed for iPad).
All our menus open by pressing the left mouse button (or pressing one finger on the Touchpad). This action is recognized as UITapGestureRecognizer. Everything works great.
But we need to show the menu by right-clicking the mouse (or pressing with two fingers on the Touchpad). We are unable to create this action.

We tried through UILongPressGestureRecognizer and other GestureRecognizers, but it doesn't work.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Please tell me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68635715/16157878